# First-Party Cookies Not Found On Same Web Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, cookies, iis-7

I have two sites set up on one Windows 2008 IIS server. On the first site, the user hits the web page and the following simple C# code is used to create a cookie.

```
<%
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
    myCookie.Value = "Hi";
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
>%
```

I've verified that this site can in fact "see" the cookie and I can use the following code to display its value:

```
<% Response.Write(Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"].Value); %>
```

On the other site hosted on the exact same server.  I use the following code to see if the cookie is assigned a value:

```
if (Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"] == null)
{
    lblErr.Text = "Cookie is null.";
}
else
{
    lblErr.Text = Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"].Value;
}
```

It's null.  Just a few days before, however, it wasn't null. In the full code of the actual site, it was working for all but a few users.  In trying to troubleshoot these particular users, it stopped working for everyone.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I need to pass values between two sites which are completely independent and unaware of each other.  I thought first-party cookies work fine if on the same server.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are associated with the URL they come from - the browser would not send to site B the cookies received from site A (and vice-versa).

**EDIT**

If the problem is user-dependant maybe it is related to the cookie settings in the browser - if some user are blocking cookies for example.

Comment: Even if the URL was www.server.com/Thisdirectory and the other URL was www.server.com/Thatdirectory?

Comment: Why did it work for 385 different test users and then stop suddenly?

Comment: No, those URLs are on the same site, so the same cookies should be visible to both.

Comment: That's the problem, they aren't.  They were, for 385 test users.  Now it just stopped suddenly.  I don't know what happened.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely not browser dependent. It won't even work if all cookies are accepted, in Chrome, IE, whatever browser it is.  It's just not working at all.

Comment: Also, it's not even a separate website in IIS, it's a separate virtual directory.

Comment: So it turns out that the asp.net application in the virtual directory isn't generating cookies even for itself.  If I try to create a cookie and read it on the same page of that site, it's still null.  Something else is definitely wrong, maybe with IIS, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `Path` property to `"/"` and make sure the sites share the same domain name.

If they are on different sub domains, set the `Domain` property to `domainname.com` (your domain name).

Edit:

Your code should look like this:

```
if (Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"] == null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
    myCookie.Path = "/";
    myCookie.Domain = "domain.com";
    myCookie.Value = "Hi";
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);

    lblErr.Text = "Cookie was null.";
}
else
{
    lblErr.Text = Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"].Value;
}
```

Comment: Is there any caching in the system? Group policies about cookies? Also, I'd pay attention to how and where you place the code to check the cookie value. See update in my answer for pattern.

Comment: Cookies work fine on one site but not the other.  Can't be the browser since it is in fact working on one site.  The problem is no longer that one site in one virtual directory cannot see the cookies created by the other, the problem is now that one site can't even see the cookies created by itself. Something else is totally wrong.  It's like something broke.

Answer (score 0):

The expiry time you set for the cookie (one minute from now) is a bit too short. Try setting it to 6 months in the future and see if that helps.

Comment: Yeah that isn't the issue. The issue is that cookies cannot be used across virtual directories. Although they were able to be, for nearly 400 users for a short time somehow, magically.